# vs 2017 entity core 2 not using the right data directory

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

experiencing an odd issue I've yet to see on any of my other machines. This is a fresh laptop, so I have installed VS 2017, SQL Server 2017 express, then created a quick sample project using one of the stock .net core projects (with authentication stored "in-app"). This, of course, creates some basic entity migrations and DB context.

When I run I'm getting access denied errors. So, of course, I checked SQL service default user which is an admin. I then run basic migration commands and receive this

[image: dummy web app illustrating odd SQL behavior with EF]

So, of course, my next step was to double check the default data locations of SQL since it appears to be trying to store it in C:\Users root?! I have never had to bother touching this during install, but worth a look. And of course, they are as I expected in their default locations of C:\Program Files\ etc

[image: sql settings]

Rapidly running out of things to try at this point - and considering this is a fresh windows 10 install, with bare-bones vs 2017 and SQL express 2017 it feels a lot like a bug here. Everything is a default if you were to File -> New Project -> .NET Core Web Application with INdividual accounts.

Anyone have any thoughts or things worth trying? Why is it trying to store my DB in C:\Users? Connection string -

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication3-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Thanks!
-Marc

Comment: What is your pc name??

Answer (score 1):

You are **not using SQL Server Express**.

The local string says `(localdb)`, which is the SQL Server engine running in **user space**. This is a big difference. Usually SQL Server or SQL Server express runs as service. `(localdb)` **is not** an alias for `localhost` (loopback address). It's a special name for a minified version of SQL Server which runs in user space.

When SQL Server runs as a service, it needs to have read/write permissions to the folder it writes. This is usually **NOT THE CASE** when the file is located within the User folder.

LocalDB on the other side, is always started when you start debugging your application and runs with the permissions of the user. So if your file was created by an admin user or outside of a directory you have write permissions.

Also, when you mount a database to SQL Server (Express), then the file is protected from write access to other applications, so LocalDB can't open it neither.

LocalDB is made for development to offer most of the SQL Server features but without all the hard setup and permanently running service in the background.

Essentially you have two options:

1. Use the SQL Server connection string as @TanvirArjel suggested
2. Detach the database from SQL Server express, copy it to your user folder (`C:\Users\<myusername>\`) and then correct the path to it

   Then it should just work.

Notice that LocalDB is not meant to run in production, so you will likely experience issues when trying to run it in IIS (IIS Express and Console applications and WPF work fine).

Reasons for LocalDb not working with IIS is because ASP.NET (Core) applications within IIS run with a special user, but LocalDbs are always created in the users profile folder. Now, the accounts used by IIS don't have a profile and can't create the database and can't access any database outside (since localDbs are stored in user folder only the user who created it has access to it).

Here some source on it and the reasons behind it.
[Using LocalDb with IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/)

Answer (score 0):

**Write the connection string as follows.Hope it will work...**

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=YourPcName\\SQLExpressInstanceName;Database=aspnet-WebApplication3-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Comment: Since most people don't have a built-in diff viewer it's good practice to explain your answer rather than only showing code.